# How to unwrap and bake object created with array modifier?

Tags: uv, modifiers, texture-baking

Noob here!
I have a texture that applied to a plane

[image]

...and duplicated with an array modifier as so...

[image]

What I am trying to accomplish is bake the image(s) onto the resulting mesh.  Is there any way to do that?

Each time I try to UV unwrap the mesh it screws up the array textures and uses the single image.
[image]

My purpose for doing this is to bake the texture on an image an import into Unity.  Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Array modifiers will duplicate the uv of the original mesh so any texture you are using on the base mesh will automatically duplicate it over to the array. If you are wanting for each segment to have its own individual texture then you will have to apply the modifier first before you can make adjustments individually.

Comment: The modifier has been applied.  What I am trying to do is take the resulting texture compilation and bake it into a single image I can then apply to the resulting mesh.
Or maybe I should be asking another question... How would I import such a construct into Unity?

Answer (score 0):

Once the array has been applied, unwrap using Follow Active Quads and then arrange the resultant UV map (by positioning, rotating, scaling the entire island) so that one ‘face’ is scaled and positioned to fit the whole image. This should result in the image repeating identically for each face.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I have been able to unwrap using Follow Active Quads.  I have positioned the image on the selected face and it seems to be working.  What I can't figure out is - how do I now bake the entire road piece to single image (to be imported to Unity as a texture).  Each time I try to do it I get the single road image piece.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/hbjmwhlzo6z81my/Capture.PNG?dl=0

Comment: Ah, I see. In that case you should be able to add a second UV map, arranged how you want the final result to bake. In the material use the UV Mapping node to specify the UV map described above. In the Mesh properties set the new UV map (the one for the final bake result) as the ‘default’ (renderable) UV map and don’t forget to add a new Image Texture for the bake result (and ensure it’s selected). Now baking should use one UV map for the material and the other for the bake. I’ve not got access to a computer so I can’t provide nore detail at the moment but hope this helps.

Comment: Appreciate the help.  I was able to add a new UV map to my mesh using the Data Object Tab, but I cannot seem to unwrap my mesh correctly.  The closest I get is Project from View, which gives me this...where my image has reverted to a single stretched image 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/920e0bhlivz5ixb/Capture1.PNG?dl=0